# Geocoding all pincode of India

Tags: python, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am trying to geocode all the pincode of India using Python. However, it's very slow and taking a long time to do that.

I have tried using [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) & [geocoder](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/) libraries but its very slow. Any other way to do that efficiently? If I have to do that on the fly for thousand addresses in one go.

India has ~ 150,000 pincode.

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: define `very slow`

Comment: @njzk2: Geopy geocodes around 2 pincode/second. Geocoder is faster but still 3 pincode/second.

Comment: @depperm: I am using the sample code mentioned here: https://github.com/geopy/geopy#geocoding. Running each request in a loop reading from a CSV file.

Comment: can't you simply multi-thread it?

Comment: 2 code / sec will take about a day. you only need to do it once, so I am not sure where the problem is?

Comment: @njzk2: Then, I have to build a system which does geocoding in real time. I am looking if something like this already exist else I will have to go ahead and build it.

Comment: of 2 things 1: either a/ you need to geocode in real time, in which case you can simply call one of those APIs, and you'll simply have a 1/2 second delay, or b/ you need all the geocodes statically, in which case, you can simply get all the geocodes once, and it will take at most 1 day, but only once.